# how to get one row by combine two row on ID?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i am working in sql server 2012
I have table attend_record

My table

[image]

i want result like this:

[image]

kindly help for this issue?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always have 1 to 1 relation?  1 in for 1 out?

Comment: i have only one table no 1 to 1 relation.kindly check now i have uploaded in picture thanks

Comment: Can the out be next day?  In at 8 pm, out at 4 am?

Comment: Please put your sample data and result as formatted text in the post, as opposed to images. It will make it much easier for people to help. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only 1 column from out result, and state 1 is always in, and state 2 is always out :

```
;with tmpIn as (select * from <table> where attend_state = 'c/in'),
tmpOut as (select * from <table> where attend_state = 'c/out')
select emp_CA_no, attend_date attend_date1,
(select top 1 attend_date from tmpOut where attend_date > tmpIn.attend_date and emp_AC_no = tmpIn.emp_AC_no) attend_date2,
'c/in', 'c/out'
from tmpIn
```

Note I didn't spread date and time into 2 columns.  Instead, I used datetime for in and datetime for out.